# Simple query issue, where clause

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get a query work! 
I have this query right here:

```
$data = mysql_query( "SELECT date, time,location,type_of_payment,
        basket_information, user_id FROM retailer")
```

I have this variable also:

```
$getuser[0]['user_id']
```

I need to set a clause, but i have difficulties in the way of writing the query. Can someone help me editing it please?

```
$data = mysql_query( "SELECT date, time,location,type_of_payment,
        basket_information, user_id FROM retailer 
        WHERE user_id = $getuser[0]['user_id']")
```

Thanks..

Comment: Unless `$getuser[0]['user_id']` is from the database (and not user entered data), you really should be escaping it to prevent SQL injection. If you used PDO or mysqli, you wouldn't have to bother with escaping as long as you used prepared queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$data = mysql_query( "SELECT date, time,location,type_of_payment,
                      basket_information, user_id FROM retailer 
                      WHERE user_id=".$getuser[0]['user_id'])
```

And, you should really use [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead of `mysql`.

Comment: Thanks, but when i use this it says :
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Comment: What is the contents of `$getuser[0]['user_id']`? I was assuming it was just an integer.

Comment: Are you sure the error is coming from that query? It doesn't contain a `"`, so I don't see how it could.

Comment: what does `echo "SELECT date, time,location,type_of_payment,basket_information, user_id FROM retailer WHERE user_id=".$getuser[0]['user_id'];` show?

Comment: This is the output:
SELECT date, time,location,type_of_payment,basket_information, user_id FROM retailer WHERE user_id=

Comment: Ok, so in that case your problem is that `$getuser[0]['user_id']` is empty. Make sure you are setting it correctly.

Comment: Well if i print $getuser[0]['user_id'] i get an integer, but anyways, i'll try to figure it out

Comment: No problem! I suspect that there must be something wrong with how you are assigning the variable, but I can't really say more than that. If my answer solved your issue though, do you mind accepting it?

Answer (score 2):

You're running into a PHP parser glitch:

```
$data = mysql_query( "SELECT [..snip..]  WHERE user_id=$getuser[0]['user_id']")
```

you're trying to insert a multidimensional array (strike #1) into a double-quoted string, while using quoted array keys (strike #2). PHP's parser isn't greedy, and will not "see" the `['user_id']` as part of the array reference. That's why there's `{}`. Plus, quoting keys in array references in double-quoted strings will produce a warning, so... try this instead:

```
$data = "....... WHERE user_id={$getuser[0]['user_id']}")
                               ^---                   ^---
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't read an array in the SQL code, before you execute the code you could do:

```
$user = $getuser[0]['user_id'];
$data = mysql_query( "SELECT date, time,location,type_of_payment,
                      basket_information, user_id FROM retailer 
                      WHERE user_id = $user");
```

Comment: Hey thanks, but it doesn't work this way.. i mean if i print :echo $getuser[0]['user_id']; i can do it, but if i assign it to another variable and print it, it won't work!